# В Django не работает фильтр center

Tags: python, django

В шаблоне использовал фильтр center, но он не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="list-group">
                {% for i in categories %}
                    <a href="/category/{{ i.pk }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ i.title|center:"2" }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Только обучаюсь django, так что даже не знаю где копать.

Comment: а какое поведение ожидалось, что они будут по центру все?

Comment: Да, можно использовать пробелы, но это не красиво)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации по [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/) дан очень хороший пример, что означает `center`:

```
"{{ value|center:"15" }}"
```

здесь значить, что `value` будет помещен в строку из 15 знаков по середине. Т.е. если `value ="Django"` тогда `"     Django    "`.

У вас же стоит значение `2` в которое по определению не может поместиться ваша строка. Попробуйте увеличить значение в кавычках. Например:

```
{{ i.title|center:"21" }}
```

Также рассмотрите возможность использовать `css` для верстки ваших элементов на странице.

Comment: Использовал, не помогает ставил и 20 и 200 и 10

Comment: @DarMaster браузер сжимает пробелы, которые прилетают из данной директивы. Используйте css для достижения нужного вам результата

Comment: Понял, спасибо.